# Having trouble iterating through a json array in react

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, api, dictionary

I don't seem to be able to pull data out of a lower level in a json array. I can pull the top level data, however get an error trying to pull anything further. I've only just started to learns API's and React, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
  {
    containerId: 1,
    containerName: "Finance",
    containerDescription: null,
    vitems: [
            {
                itemId: 2,
                itemName: "Sun",
                itemDescription: null,
                itemType: "Maintain",
                itemTypeDescription: null,
                css: "darkgreen"
            },
            {
                itemId: 3,
                itemName: "Concur",
                itemDescription: null,
                itemType: "Maintain",
                itemTypeDescription: null,
                css: "darkgreen"
            },
            {
                itemId: 4,
                itemName: "Basware",
                itemDescription: null,
                itemType: "Maintain",
                itemTypeDescription: null,
                css: "darkgreen"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/changeatdate/1/2019-07-01';

    fetch(API_URL)
      .then(results => {
        return results.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        let items = data.map((i) => {
          return(
            <ul key={i.containerId} className='container'>
              <h1 key={i.containerId*0.1}>{i.containerName}</h1>
              <li key={i.containerName}></li>
            </ul>
          )
        })
        this.setState({items});
      })
  }
  render() {{this.state.items}}
```

The above works (and yes - I know I need to get my keys sorted...). But how would I get the vitems to appear within the containers?

I'm really stuck, and I'm sure this is simple, so hoping someone can help me.

One thing that I did notice is that my json begins with [ as opposed to going straight to {. I'm using sequelize, with models and the use of 'include'.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this simple technique using multiple for loops

1. for loop main array length
2. for loop for vitems length

I have added a snippet

```js
var x =  [{
   containerId: 1,
   containerName: "Finance",
   containerDescription: null,
   vitems: [{
     itemId: 2,
     itemName: "Sun",
     itemDescription: null,
     itemType: "Maintain",
     itemTypeDescription: null,
     css: "darkgreen"
    },
    {
     itemId: 3,
     itemName: "Concur",
     itemDescription: null,
     itemType: "Maintain",
     itemTypeDescription: null,
     css: "darkgreen"
    },
    {
     itemId: 4,
     itemName: "Basware",
     itemDescription: null,
     itemType: "Maintain",
     itemTypeDescription: null,
     css: "darkgreen"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   containerId: 2,
   containerName: "Technology",
   containerDescription: null,
   vitems: [{
     itemId: 2,
     itemName: "Sun",
     itemDescription: null,
     itemType: "Maintain",
     itemTypeDescription: null,
     css: "darkgreen"
    },
    {
     itemId: 3,
     itemName: "Concur",
     itemDescription: null,
     itemType: "Maintain",
     itemTypeDescription: null,
     css: "darkgreen"
    },
    {
     itemId: 4,
     itemName: "Basware",
     itemDescription: null,
     itemType: "Maintain",
     itemTypeDescription: null,
     css: "darkgreen"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]

//Iterate over main array
for(let i=0; i< x.length; i++){
  const vitemsLength = x[i].vitems.length;
  //Iterate over vitems array based on it's length
  for(let j=0; j < vitemsLength; j++){
    console.log(x[i].vitems[j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the vitems in the way mentioned below:

```
<ul key={i.containerId} className='container'>
    <h1>{i.containerName}</h1>
    {
        i.vitems.map(el => <li key={el.itemId}>{el.itemName}</li>)
    }
</ul>
```

Key is not needed on h1 tag.